# kernel matrix computation outside SVM training in kernlab

Tags: r, svm, kernlab

I was developing a new algorithm that generates a modified kernel matrix for training with a SVM and encountered a strange problem.

For testing purposes I was comparing the SVM models learned using kernelMatrix interface and normal kernel interface. For example,

```
# Model with kernelMatrix computation within ksvm
svp1 <- ksvm(x, y, type="C-svc", kernel=vanilladot(), scaled=F)
# Model with kernelMatrix computed outside ksvm
K <- kernelMatrix(vanilladot(), x)
svp2 <- ksvm(K, y, type="C-svc")
identical(nSV(svp1), nSV(svp2))
```

Note that I have turned scaling off, as I am not sure how to perform scaling on kernel matrix.

From my understanding both `svp1` and `svp2` should return the same model. However I observed that this not true for a few datasets, for example `glass0` from [KEEL](http://sci2s.ugr.es/keel/imbalanced.php).

What am I missing here?

Comment: Could you post the code you're using to load x and y?  I just tried this with toy data and the two evaluated to identical for me.

Comment: @Aabglov using the glass0 data set I found the same error OP posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this has to do with same issue posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691036/in-r-why-is-result-of-ksvm-using-user-defined-linear-kernel-different-from-tha).  kernlab appears to treat the calculation of ksvm differently when explicitly using vanilladot() because it's class is 'vanillakernel' instead of 'kernel'.

if you define your own vanilladot kernel with a class of 'kernel' instead of 'vanillakernel' the code will be equivalent for both:

```
kfunction.k <- function(){
   k <- function (x,y){crossprod(x,y)}
   class(k) <- "kernel"
   k}
l<-0.1 ; C<-1/(2*l)

svp1 <- ksvm(x, y, type="C-svc", kernel=kfunction.k(), scaled=F)

K <- kernelMatrix(kfunction.k(),x)

svp2 <- ksvm(K, y, type="C-svc", kernel='matrix', scaled=F)

identical(nSV(svp1), nSV(svp2))
```

It's worth noting that svp1 and svp2 are both different from their values in the original code because of this change.